# Rails g figaro:install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I know this question has already been asked in these pages, but the accepted answer repeats the basic figaro instructions, without addressing the actual error. I'm a newbie, so I'd appreciate any help . . .

I've included gem 'figaro' in my Gemfile, I've run "bundle install" from my command line. But when I enter "Rails g figaro:install" at the command line, I get the error that "Could not find generator Figaro:install."

I've searched this all over the web, and all I can find are the basic instructions. Can anyone tell me why Rails can't find the generator?

Thank you.

Comment: Hmm. try running `gem list` to see if figaro is installed.

Comment: You may need to restart the terminal: https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro/issues/180

Answer (score 6):

At time of writing, it looks like the Figaro stable version has changed recently from 0.7.0 to 1.0.0.

The `rails g figaro:install` command is from 0.7.0, and my *guess* is that 1.0.0 is installed.

To check the version used:

```
cd path/to/a/rails/project/directory
bundle exec gem query '\Afigaro\z'
```

Assuming figaro 1.0.0 is being used by the app, then the figaro commands you'll be using from now on are these (these replace the commands used by Figaro 0.7.0):

```
figaro install # Installs figaro into your app
figaro heroku:set -e production # Copies env config from application.yml to Heroku
```

Answer (score 2):

Figaro gem [Readme](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro#getting-started) tells that to install use

```
$ figaro install
```

You are using `figaro:install`

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error in my development, This is because of figaro updated version 1.1 +. Please read the **Getting Started** in [Figaro Gem](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) installation part.

give the following command after `bundle install`

```
bundle exec figaro install
```

It will generate the following files

```
  create  config/application.yml
  append  .gitignore
```

Answer (score 0):

For heroku just use:

```
bundle exec figaro heroku:set -e production
```